# Catching Errors in Meteor Iron-Router Route waitOn Function

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor publish function, and I'm throwing an error in that publish function to be caught by the subscriber. I'm using iron-router, and in the 'waitOn' function I'm subscribing to the publication. For some reason my error function isn't being called when I throw the error from the publication, and I'm not sure why. Help is much appreciated!

Here is my route with my subscription (to `'assignmentsByGroup'`) and my on error function (`onErrorfunction`):

```
this.route('assignmentsList',
{path: '/groups/:groupId',
  waitOn: function() {
  var onErrorfunction = function(error, result)
  {
    console.log("onErrorfunction called");
    if(error)
    {
      console.log("Error!");
      alert(error.reason);
    }
  };
  return [Meteor.subscribe('assignmentsByGroup', this.params.groupId, onErrorfunction), Meteor.subscribe("groupById", this.params.groupId)];
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      groupId: this.params.groupId
    }
  }
}
);
```

And here is my publish function:

```
Meteor.publish("assignmentsByGroup", function(groupId)
{
try
{
  if(_.contains(Groups.findOne({_id: groupId}).members, this.userId))
    {
        return Assignments.find({group: groupId});
    }
    else
    {
    var errorToThrow = new Meteor.Error(401, "Access denied: you cannot view assignments unless you are a member of this group.");
        this.error(errorToThrow);
    }
}
catch(err)
{
  this.error(err);
}
});
```

Comment: This might seem obvious but are you sure that your publish function reaches the else-block? Can you confirm that with a console.log there?

Comment: I just checked, and it is reaching the else-block, so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was my onError callback syntax. I passed the subscription method a function, which is interpreted as an onReady function, only called when this.ready() is called in the publish function. I changed `Meteor.subscribe('assignmentsByGroup', this.params.groupId, onErrorfunction)` to `Meteor.subscribe('assignmentsByGroup', this.params.groupId, {onError: onErrorfunction})` and it worked! Also, you can still have a try and catch statement in the publish function; the error is still thrown properly with or without it, but with it you can also catch other internal server errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try/catch block. You are already in a function that returns a publication or an error.

When you do the try/catch, the actual error that you throw (a Meteor.Error) is caught and passed/thrown into the catch as a regular javascript error.

But the subscription is waiting for a proper Meteor.Error

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to have solved the problem. Even after removing the try/catch statement, onErrorfunction (the callback) still isn't being called. Is my syntax for an onError callback correct?

Comment: it looks quite correct, I can't think of a reason why this is not working :(